# Based on Check-box selection product enabled(product.active=1) in the database

Tags: php, html, ajax, laravel

I have checkbox on my image, and there is a checkbox on each images, these images are coming from database, i want if i checked(click) the checkbox, the product must be enabled(`ACTIVE = 1`) in the data base, means in database `ACTIVE` field is there,defaultly this field is 0.

So after clicking the checkbox the value must be change 0 to 1 in data base and after unchecked it must be  set the `0` in database.

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="{{$product->img}}">
  <div class="caption">
    <p>
      <a href="#" id="modal_product" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{$product->id}}">Edit</a>
      <input type="checkbox" name="tag_1" id="tag_1" value="yes" >Visible
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where's your ajax code? what error you're getting? did you try anything?

Comment: @NishanthMatha ,No not yet,actually i am not getting how to do this,bec from data base we can get the data but how to modified that i am not getting,am not good in ajax!!!!

Comment: refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php